# Matplotlib: uneven grid size when plotting diagonal matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scaling, distortion

I have noticed a frustrating problem with Pythons Matplotlib where matrix plotting produces
an uneven grid. This issue is persistent with and without high DPI, as well as in EPS files.

The following code is used for the image generation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((200,200))
# Set the diagonal to 1
arr[np.arange(200), np.arange(200)] = 1

plt.matshow(arr)
plt.savefig('matshow_test.png', dpi=1000)
```

DPI=1000:
[image: Text]

Which has the sizes 65x65, 90x90, 95x95, 90x90, 95x95 and so on.

DPI=default
[image: Text]

Which varies between 1x1 and 2x2 for each cell.

EPS rendered in latex:
[image: Text]

Which is clearly distorted.

**My questions are:**

1. Why is this the default behaviour of Matplotlib?
2. How can I fix this?

Using Python 3.9.10 with Matplotlib 3.5.1

Comment: Personally I found matplotlib exports to pdf most satisfiying for getting neat results, maybe try that?

Comment: I just found that pdf and svg suffer the same distortion. Svg export even inlines a png raster graphic. That is horrible, in my opinion.

Comment: Since I was trying to use the graph for a latex file, the PDF option was not plug-and-play due to the lack of image dimension definition. Even after defining the dimensions with natwidth/natheight it just made most of the latex PDF blank after the import location. So sticking with EPS was the way to go.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you include the images and what tex compiler do you use? I always used pdf pictures with the \includegraphic command and never had issues with dimesions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matplotlib function `matshow` uses an antialiasing filter on the images. Unfortunately it is enabled even for vector graphic backends such as (e)ps, pdf or svg. That means, the image is rasterized, antialiased to a specific size and than inlined in the vector graphic.

Antialiasing takes into account a specific display resolution (dpi) and image size. If you change those parameters when viewing an image (for example when zooming in) the image can get heavily distorted, as you have experienced.

There is a discussion about the default antialiasing for matplotlib imshow (and also matshow which uses the same mechanism) [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_antialiasing.html).

You should be able to fix your issue (and get true vector graphics) by disabling the antialiasing with the

```
matshow(..., interpolation='none')
```

option.

Comment: For my case, the solution was to use eps with `interpolation=None`